# Saving CSS in SalesForce website

Tags: visualforce, css, error-messages, stylesheets

I keep getting this error that's driving me nuts whenever I try to save my CSS file.  What are SalesForce' restrictions on CSS?  What would cause this?  I'm quite certain that there is nothing wrong with my CSS code as I've thoroughly tested it outside of SalesForce.  It is only an issue when I try to save it in SalesForce.

[image]

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: None..  Textmate 1.5

Comment: Is this site.com, or communities? Does the same CSS upload as a static resource?

Comment: Could you upload your CSS Stylesheet so we can take a look